# calling the same service 20 times vs using the kafka

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, spring-kafka

i have a java springboot service-A which calls service-B to create a product.

unfortunately service-B can accept only one product at once , in this scenario if i have a 20 products i may end up calling service-B 20 times , so to solve this is it better to make a multi threading parellal call or is it better to create a separate Queue service like kafka and send all these products to kafka and process it from kafka service ?

Comment: We need to know more about your service B. It is clear that it cannot accept a batch of products per request. But if your service is able to accept requests in parallel, then there is no need in a queue in between. In other words: is your service B thread safe?